# Lyx minted environment layout

Tags: lyx, minted, lyx-layouts

Before I resolved a problem to set up a `minted` environment in LaTeX. 
Now, I would like to add this environment as a LyX layout. 
I have tried with

```
Style MatlabCode
Category              MainText
Margin                Static
LatexType             Environment
LatexName             matlabcode
NextNoIndent          1
LeftMargin            MMM
RightMargin           MMM
ParIndent             MM
ParSkip               0
ItemSep               0
TopSep                0.5
BottomSep             0.5
ParSep                0
Align                 Block
AlignPossible         Block, Left, Right, Center
Preamble
    \usepackage{minted}
    \newminted{matlab}{mathescape,linenos=true}
EndPreamble
```

End

Everything works and pdflatex gives me a nice PDF. The problem is that, when I use the environment, which is similar to a quotation layout in LyX, in the output I get blank lines, like this

[image]

And those weird brackets, since it should be just `[2;3]`

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Can you please post a [LyX minimal example](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample) ? In this case that would be a LyX file with a Local Layout that you pasted in here and that produces the output that you pasted here.

Comment: Hi, here there is an example https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8b4tp1ho94z41ok/9VwyKZjego Remember to put -shell-escape in the pdflatex option in the Tools -> Preferences

Comment: I put also the layouts file. You must reconfigure LyX after leaving that file in the layouts directory

Comment: Thanks for the minimal example. Note that you might be interested to know that you could just put your layout directly in Document > Settings > Local Layout. This is useful when developing your layout (e.g. making a lot of tweaks), useful for document-specific layouts (which this will probably not be), and also useful for minimal examples (no need for reconfigure and just one file).

Comment: Also note (for anyone else) that the pygmentize package can be installed with `sudo apt-get install python-pygments` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I know, the local layout directory is in ~/.lyx  I already had `pygments` , that's why it compiles well, but the output is weird. Thanks for the tips

Comment: I was giving you advice for how to improve on posting a minimal example. You should always give the prerequisites that are necessary (in this case the pygmentize package). And using LyX's local layout is useful for encapsulating things. I'm not referring to `~/.lyx`. That is something different. I'm referring to Document > Settings > Local Layout. If you put the layout in there, everything is self-contained and it makes it easy for someone to come along and try to help. It's also useful for other reasons.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following lines:

```
PassThru                      1
ParbreakIsNewline             1
```

`PassThru` tells LyX "don't escape my input. It's not LaTeX".

`ParbreakIsNewline tells LyX not to start a new paragraph for line breaks in this layout.

This gives the following layout:

```
Style MatlabCode
Category              MainText
Margin                Static
LatexType             Environment
LatexName             matlabcode
NextNoIndent          1
LeftMargin            MMM
RightMargin           MMM
PassThru              1
ParbreakIsNewline             1
ParIndent             MM
ParSkip               0
ItemSep               0
TopSep                0.5
BottomSep             0.5
ParSep                0
Align                 Block
AlignPossible         Block, Left, Right, Center
Preamble
        \usepackage{minted}
        \newminted{matlab}{mathescape,linenos=true}
    EndPreamble
End
```

Please read Help > Customization for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take a look to the Help, I didn't find that information before.